# Using order by clause with UNION issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting the following error when I user Order by with UNION.

"The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."

```
declare @results table (hdate date, name varchar(100), id1 int)

insert into @results select cast('10-01-2015' as date), 'val1 1', 1
insert into @results select cast('10-02-2015' as date), 'val2 2', 2

insert into @results select cast('10-03-2015' as date), 'thanks 1', 3
insert into @results select cast('10-04-2015' as date), 'thanks 2', 3

select  (DATENAME(dw, hdate) + ', ' + 
        DATENAME(mm, hdate) + ' '  + 
      DATENAME(dd, hdate)) AS h_date, name AS h_name from @results where id1 in (1,2) 
order by id1
UNION
SELECT (STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + (DATENAME(dw, hdate) + ', ' + 
       DATENAME(mm, hdate) + ' '  + 
       DATENAME(dd, hdate))
        FROM @results
        WHERE id1 = 3
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '')
    ) AS h_date, 'Giving Day' AS h_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in following:

```
declare @results table (hdate date, name varchar(100), id1 int)

insert into @results select cast('10-01-2015' as date), 'val1 1', 1
insert into @results select cast('10-02-2015' as date), 'val2 2', 2

insert into @results select cast('10-03-2015' as date), 'thanks 1', 3
insert into @results select cast('10-04-2015' as date), 'thanks 2', 3

SELECT  id1,
        (DATENAME(dw, hdate) + ', ' + 
        DATENAME(mm, hdate) + ' '  + 
        DATENAME(dd, hdate)) AS h_date, name AS h_name from @results where id1 in (1,2) 

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT id1,(STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + (DATENAME(dw, hdate) + ', ' + 
               DATENAME(mm, hdate) + ' '  + 
               DATENAME(dd, hdate))
        FROM @results r2
        WHERE  r1.id1 = r2.id1
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '')
    ) AS h_date, 'Giving Day' AS h_name
FROM @results r1
WHERE id1 = 3 
ORDER BY id1
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you can't use an ORDER BY with a UNION. So you have to wrap it up in a sub-query before ordering it:

```
select h_date, h_name from (
select  (DATENAME(dw, hdate) + ', ' + 
        DATENAME(mm, hdate) + ' '  + 
      DATENAME(dd, hdate)) AS h_date, name AS h_name 
      , id1
      from @results 
      where id1 in (1,2) 
UNION
SELECT (STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + (DATENAME(dw, hdate) + ', ' + 
       DATENAME(mm, hdate) + ' '  + 
       DATENAME(dd, hdate))
        FROM @results
        WHERE id1 = 3
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '')
    ) AS h_date, 'Giving Day' AS h_name, 3 as id1) q
order by id1
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
declare @results table (hdate date, name varchar(100), id1 int)

insert into @results select cast('10-01-2015' as date), 'val1 1', 1
insert into @results select cast('10-02-2015' as date), 'val2 2', 2

insert into @results select cast('10-03-2015' as date), 'thanks 1', 3
insert into @results select cast('10-04-2015' as date), 'thanks 2', 3

select * FROM ( SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT (DATENAME(dw, hdate) + ', ' + 
        DATENAME(mm, hdate) + ' '  + 
      DATENAME(dd, hdate)) AS h_date, name AS h_name from @results where id1 in (1,2) 
ORDER BY id1)A
UNION 
select * FROM ( SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT (STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + (DATENAME(dw, hdate) + ', ' + 
       DATENAME(mm, hdate) + ' '  + 
       DATENAME(dd, hdate))
        FROM @results
        WHERE id1 = 3
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '')
    ) AS h_date, 'Giving Day' AS h_name
    ) AS B
```